# Kubernetes: Trying to load OPA policy via kube-mgmt by creating a configmap containing the policy but the configmap has none as annotation

Tags: kubernetes, open-policy-agent

## Wished Behavior

1. Write OPA policy which check if image-name contain default latest tag. The following is my .rego file :

```
package kubernetes.admission

import data.kubernetes.namespaces


deny[msg] {
    input.request.kind.kind == "Pod"
    input.request.operation == "CREATE"
    container := input.request.object.spec.containers[_]
    [image_name, image_tag] := split(container.image, ":")
    image_tag == "latest"
    msg := sprintf("Invalid image tag")
}
```

2. Load the policy by creating a configmap. I used the following command:

```
kubectl create configmap registry-whitelist --from-file image-checker.rego
```

> The default namespace in my current context is `opa`.

3. After that it's supposed that I can exercise the policy by creating a pod with latest tag and it has to be rejected.

### Actual Behavior

Pods with latest tags are created successfully and they are not rejected.

### Steps to Reproduce the Problem

I followed these tips https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/kubernetes-debugging/ .

So, it's expected that the created configmap `registry-whitelist` has `openpolicyagent.org/policy-status` as annotations, however it has `<none>` as value, also I have checked logs of `kube-mgmt` container however they didn't help me. The only interesting log i get is when i try to delete the configmap `registry-whitelist` I can see the following log :

**level=error msg="Failed to delete policy opa/registry-whitelist/image-checker.rego: code resource_not_found: storage_not_found_error: policy id "opa/registry-whitelist/image-checker.rego""**

Comment: could you provide output of `kubectl get cm registry-whitelist  -o yaml`?

Comment: Thank you for your help however it works now .. the problem was that i had some errors in my policy (I'm new in rego language and opa stuffs ) so the kube-mgmt takes some time before adding the annotations when the policy has errors this is why it was <none> at first .. however i don't know why it took too much to add the annotations maybe because I'm using opa with a bare metal cluster

Comment: Please post solution as an answer. It might help others users who have similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved: actually my policy which is writen in rego had some errors this is why kube-mgmt took some time before adding the annotations to the new created configmap. After a while I found an annotation saying that my policy had errors .